# Qual melhor maneira de armazenar imagens em um app iOS?

Tags: ios, web-service, imagem, core-data, armazenamento

Estou elaborando um app, e li em vários sites e artigos sobre como armazenar imagem no Core Data ou no diretório do app. 
 Porém fiquei em dúvida qual seria o melhor modo.

Gostaria de saber, qual seria a melhor design para este caso.
Para entender melhor o que planejo, o app irá receber a descrição de um produto e uma imagem para representar este produto. Como o app irá ter vários produtos minha preocupação é tentar manter tudo o máximo possível organizado.

Comment: Der mais detalhes sobre o que você já tem.

Comment: Eu ja implementei toda a interface e navegacao, e escolhi o core data para armazenar os dados. Porem so fiquei um duvida sobre o armazenamento das imagens. Quais seriam esses detalhes?

Comment: Quando você diz vários, você se refere a mais ou menos quantos produtos? Se forem muitos lhe aconselho diretório.

Comment: 52 produtos no momento e possivelmente nao vai ficar muito mais doq isso. Talvez chegue aos 70 no maximo.

Comment: Blz, outra coisa, estas imagens dos produtos, você vai querer que seja feito back up junto ao app para o iCloud?

Comment: Nao. É um app simples, apenas para servir como catalogo, o user nao vai precisar fazer nada. Apenas abrir o app e olhar. Nao vai alhaver upload de imagens por parte do app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As duas opções principais, como você disse (e como mencionando [nessa pergunta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158322/2305521)), são:

1. Guardar o arquivo no disco e guardar o caminho para a imagem no Core Data.
2. Guardar o binário do arquivo da imagem no Core Data.

Preciso dizer que concordo com [Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong) e acho que a opção *#1* é melhor por permite fazer `lazy loading` da imagem.

Um exemplo de uso interessante é guardar a URL para a imagem no Core Data e a primeira vez que essa imagem for requisitada ela é cacheada localmente e essa URL é substituída pelo path da imagem.

Outra solução que já vi ser implementada quando há uma regra de negócios de quanto tempo a imagem deve permanecer cacheada é guardar a URL para ela e incluir um campo `lastUsed`, ela é baixada e salva localmente e após esse tempo pré-definido deve ser baixada novamente. Essa solução minimiza o espaço utilizado e ao mesmo tempo mantém as imagens mais usadas disponíveis.

Se optar pela opção *#2* de uma olhada no [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW5) e na pergunta [Core Data iPad/iPhone BLOBS vs File system for 20k PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596702/core-data-ipad-iphone-blobs-vs-file-system-for-20k-pdfs).

Comment: Vou optar em usar a primeira opção e vou criar uma lógica para tratar as imagens que forem substituídas! 

 obrigado pela ajuda!!